# Show that 5n + 3 and 7n + 4 are relatively prime for any n 2 N. Show that s and t are not unique.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

I know that s = 7 and t = -5, but I'm having trouble showing that they are not unique. I've been just guess and checking, is there a better way to compute this?

Comment: What are $s$ and $t$?

Comment: You *really* should specify what $s$ and $t$ are. I'm assuming you mean$s(5n + 3) - t(7n + 4) = 1$ but without including that in your question, this post is utterly meaningless.  You can't assume that because you have the text of a problem in front of you that we do too.  That'd mean either there is only one textbook and all mathematician use it, or that we are psychic.  Neither of those is the case.

Comment: What does "any n 2 N" mean?  What are $s$ and $t$?  Fix this question.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$7(5n+3)-5(7n+4)=1$$and therefore $5n+3$ and $7n+4$ are relatively prime. But it is also true that$$\bigl(7+(7n+4)\bigr)(5n+3)-\bigl(5+(5n+3)\bigr)(7n+4)=1.$$

Comment: This answer would be improved by appealing to Bezut's Lemma explicitly, and perhaps stating it as well.

Comment: @StellaBiderman That would depend on how the question is clarified.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since

$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a))$$

we have

$$\gcd(5n+3,7n+4)=\gcd(5n+3,2n+1)=\gcd(n+1,2n+1)=\gcd(n+1,n)=\gcd(n,1)=1$$

Thus for [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) exist $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$, not unique, such that

$$s\cdot(5n+3)+t\cdot(7n+4)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Note:

If $s(5n + 3) + t(7n + 4) = 1$

Then $s(5n+3) + K + t(7n + 4) - K = 1$

$(s + \frac K{5n+3})(5n+3) + (t - \frac K{7n+4})(7n+4) = 1$ .

So if $s, t$ are such that $s(5n + 3) + t(7n + 4) = 1$

Then $s + \frac K{5n+3}, $ and $t - \frac K{5n+3}$ are too.

Is it possible that there is an integer $K$ (other than $K = 0$) so that $\frac K{5n+3}$ and $\frac K{7n + 4}$ are both integers?

Is it possible that there could be more than one?

$K$ must be a multiple of $5n+3$ and $K$ must be a multiple $7n+4$.  Is that possible?  Is in possible that two different numbers could have a common multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$7(5n+3)-5(7n+4)=1  \text {  (*) } $$ $5n+3$ and $7n+4$ are relatively prime.

In order to get other coefficients you may replace $5$ with  $5$ times $\text { ( *)}$  or $7$ by $7$ times   $\text { (*)}.$